# Detect if PopupWindow is over a ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, popupwindow

When I create a PopupWindow and display it on a ScrollView, scrolling this won't move the position of the PopupWindow in any way.

So, after creating a PopupWindow, how can I programmatically discover if it is displayed on a ScrollView, so that I can create a listener and scroll it together with it?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need this answer anymore, but you can actually scroll a PopupWindow automatically by anchoring it to a view in the ScrollView using `PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(viewInsideScrollView)`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown(android.view.View)